# Configure minikuke kube-system cpu limit

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

For development, I need to reduce cpu usage of minikube.

My goal is to limit cpu usage for each kube-system pods.
I tried to modify cpu limits in kube-dns yaml editor from dashboard, but I get an error (probably because it is a system pod).

Is there a way to modify those kube-system .yml files before starting minikube and get a customized kube-system ?

I'm using minikube on windows.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you can try to use [limits for namespaces.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/)
You may create YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: cpu-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      cpu: 1
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 0.5
    type: Container
```

and add the amount which you need (for example `0.003`), then apply it to `kube-system`namespace.

```
kubectl create -f LimitRangeCPU.yaml --namespace=kube-system
```

In this case, if pods have no pre-configured resource limits, `LimitRangeCPU` will be used as default for all pods in namespace `kube-system`, where all system pods are located.

**Update**

You can export your existing configs:

```
kubectl get -o=yaml -n kube-system --export  deployment.extensions/kube-dns > kube-dns.yaml
```

than update resource usage in section:

```
resources:
   limits:
      memory: 170Mi
   requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 70Mi
```

and apply changes:

```
kubectl apply -f ./kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
```

It should help to update existing pods.

Comment: I tried but it seems hungry kube-system are already limited, so it has no effect. I think the only way is to modify original .yaml files before starting minikube.